# Custom object's vector attribute median c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am trying to find the median value from the third attribute of my objects. My objects are in a vector.

```
std::vector<Object> obj = 
   { Object {V , H , 5},
     Object {C , B , 2},
     Object {D , F , 6},
     Object {B , H , 4},
     Object {B , H , 4}
   };
```

answer:

```
4
```

I tried to use the [`nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) method but it seems that I need to access the attribute.

```
std::nth_element(obj.begin(), (obj.begin() + obj.end())/2, obj.end());
```

Comment: obj[len/2] ? is not what you need?

Comment: `std::nth_element` does partial sorting. If sorted by the numbers, median should be `4`. If correct answer is 6, then you simply need the middle element, not median.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median

Comment: Tks,  ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ. Not really, because when I do that, I have access to the Object, and I want the attribute only.

Comment: _I tried to use the nth_element method but it seems that I need to access the attribute._ This depends on how `operator<` is overloaded for `Object`. Alternatively, you have to provide a custom less predicate. (overload (3) and (4) in [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element))

Comment: @Scheff, that is true. Tks. I corrected my question.

Comment: This depends on how operator< is overloaded for Object. Alternatively, you have to provide a custom less predicate. (overload (3) and (4) in std::nth_element) Could you show me a generic example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [std::nth_element()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) applies the `operator<` to the dereferenced iterators provided as arguments.

In C++, there is no `operator<` defined for custom classes but the author is free to define (overload) one.

Alternatively, [std::nth_element()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) can be called with a custom less predicate to force a specific order.

> Could you show me a generic example ?

Here we go:
an example to get median according to a specific attribute of an object with

- partial sorting (aka. [std::nth_element()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element)) and
- a custom predicate to sort for `Object::attr`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Object {
  std::string id1, id2;
  int attr;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Object &obj)
{
  return out << "Object { id1: " << obj.id1
    << ", id2: " << obj.id2
    << ", attr: " << obj.attr << " }";
}

// demonstrate
int main()
{
  std::vector<Object> obj = 
   { Object {"V", "H" , 5},
     Object {"C", "B" , 2},
     Object {"D", "F" , 6},
     Object {"B", "H" , 4},
     Object {"B", "H" , 4}
   };
  // partial sorting with custom predicate (provided as lambda):
  std::nth_element(obj.begin(), obj.begin() + obj.size() / 2, obj.end(),
    [](const Object &obj1, const Object &obj2) { return obj1.attr < obj2.attr; });
  // get result:
  const std::vector<Object>::iterator iter
    = obj.begin() + obj.size() / 2;
  std::cout << "Median: " << *iter << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Median: Object { id1: B, id2: H, attr: 4 }
```

[**Live demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/526b79b8ddf61c37)

---

**Note:**

OP mentioned the following snippet:

```
std::nth_element(obj.begin(), obj.begin() + obj.end()/2, obj.end());
```

`obj.begin() + obj.end()/2` is yet another error.
It had to be `obj.begin() + (obj.end() - obj.begin()) / 2`.
I used instead the more compact `obj.begin() + obj.size() / 2`.

Comment: Tks, @Scheff it helped a lot. I noticed that I could use std::sort too;